# Bluetooth printing cordova

Tags: cordova, printing, bluetooth

I want to print text from my Cordova app
the printer is wirelessly connected to the phone
is there a plugin to do so?
or what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at cordova-plugin-printer?

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Comment: i dont think it supports bluetooth connection

Answer (score 0):

Try using below, it helped to print with Bluetooth.

https://github.com/CesarBalzer/Cordova-Plugin-BTPrinter